# Does Compute Engine service in cloud console use Compute Engine REST api?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In my perspective, there are three ways to interact with the GCP:

1. Cloud shell
2. Cloud SDK (gcloud)
3. REST APIs

Even before, I enabled the compute engine API manually, I can launch VMs using the GCP cloud console. But, I could see my project dashboard showing the API statistics. So my **First question: Does the compute engine web console uses the REST API in the API manager ?**

I wanted to deploy a LAMP stack using cloud launcher. According to some tutorial, we need to enable the **compute Engine API** under **API manager**. Doing so, I was able to launch the LAMP stack.

Now, I disabled the **compute Engine API** under **API manager**. I could not deploy neither using the cloud launcher nor the compute engine web console.

In Deployment manager (after initiating deploy in cloud launcher, it moves to deployment manager) I get the below error:

> Update failed with following error(s) for project settings: -- Backend
>   Provisioning Error: {compute_component FAILED_PRECONDITION: The
>   service is currently being deactivated and deactivation must complete
>   before activation can occur.};

Trying to re-enable the compute engine API also gives the above error!!

Trying the compute engine web console gives **Enabling Compute API failed. Please retry the operation.**

What could be the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First question**:
>   Does the compute engine web console uses the REST API in the API manager ?

Yes, the web console compute engine uses the compute engine API to perform all the operations. In addition to that, command line tools like gcloud and gsutil also use REST APIs of GCP.

Initially, only some APIs are enabled by default. But, when you visit the compute engine in web console, it automatically enables the API.

> **Second question**:
>   Backend Provisioning Error: {compute_component FAILED_PRECONDITION: The service is currently being deactivated and deactivation must complete before activation can occur.};

This problem was not resolved. But on asking to GCP customer centre, they requested to create new project and utilize the services in the newly created project.